# Why some view's frame become (0,0,0,0) when I try to resize other view in storyboard in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

This always happen to me in storyboard with Xcode 6.1

Here a screenshot

Before resizing table view the black view (collection view) has the size like in the picture

[image]

But whenever i start resizing tableview (by dragging the edge) my collectionview become like this

[image]

but if i resize other view both tableview and collection view become (0,0,0,0)

How can this happen? any way to solve this?

Now i have to use inspector to set my view and it is really difficult.

Comment: Certainly an Xcode bug. Try updating to 6.1, reinstalling it, restarting your Mac, etc.

Comment: sorry it happens on Xcode 6.1, don't know Xcode 6 has this problem or not but it did not occur

Comment: Even I am facing same with XCode 6.1 when ever I try to resize a view in Storyboard it just change frames of all other Views to (0,0,0,0)

Comment: Did you add any auto layout constraints to it?

Comment: @Fogmeister Auto layout did solve the problem but you know sometime i don't want to add auto layout to all my views

Comment: @Sizer if you're using AutoLayout then you have to use AutoLayout. Would you add a view and not give it a frame? AutoLayout is just the way of telling views what the frames are.

Comment: @Fogmeister, i mean i don't have to add AutoLayout to all the views right? I enables AutoLayout to storyboard, so anyway it will add automatically. What I mean is that some static VC which don't need layout to be dynamic, I will place views without specifying AutoLayout. This way is also easier for me to edit in the future, if I want to change or add some new views (no need to break AutoLayout before changing). Also if something wrong please correct me thanks.

Comment: @Sizer hmm... that may be possible. But I find it easier to add constraints to all views whether they're static or not. Besides, a static view might be in the right place for an iPhone 4 but the wrong place for an iPhone 6+. It is no longer about dynamic layouts and interface rotation etc... It's about creating an interface that will work on any device.

Answer (score 0):

To put coordinates for views in xib without having this bug set the views intrinsic size to Placeholder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this bug may occur more often when using an external display/monitor.  Hope Apple fixes it soon.  Using IB on my 13" MBPr is a bit painful.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same kind of problem with Xcode 6.1 and Yosemite : I have created a view that I have added to the main view, so it appears like a sub view in the View Controller Scene. Then I resize this subview to 320 x 568. My program works. It corresponds to the program dropit of Stanford CS193P Lecture 9. I save the project, close it and reopen it : the subview has its width and height set to 0 ! And my program does not work any more !

I tried to open the project dropit of Lecture 8 that is quite the same, which was working before (I think in Xcode 6) and same problem ! First I thought that tapping (related to the subview) was not working but found out that tapping was not working because I was tapping on a subview which has its width and height set to 0 !